# Is this a valid way of deriving the area of a circle?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, circles, area

On the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_circle#Semicircle_proof) about deriving the area of a circle, it mentions that the formula
$$
\text{area} = \pi r^2
$$
can be derived by evaluating the integral
$$
2 \int_{-r}^{r} \sqrt{r^2-x^2} \, dx \, .
$$
However, the article also seems to suggest that this can result in a circular argument if it is not done carefully:

> This particular proof may appear to beg the question, if the sine and
> cosine functions involved in the trigonometric substitution are
> regarded as being defined in relation to circles. However, as noted
> earlier, it is possible to define sine, cosine, and $\pi$ in a way that is
> totally independent of trigonometry, in which case the proof is valid
> by the change of variables formula and Fubini's theorem, assuming the
> basic properties of sine and cosine (which can also be proved without
> assuming anything about their relation to circles).

My question is: can the following argument be used to prove that the area of a circle is $\pi r^2$?

Let
$$
I=\int \sqrt{r^2-x^2} \, dx = \int \sqrt{r^2\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)^2\right)} \, dx \, = r\int \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)^2} \, dx .
$$
Then let $\theta = \arcsin(x/r)$ so that $x=r\sin\theta$. Since $dx = r\cos\theta \, d\theta$, the integral is transformed to
$$
r^2\int\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}\, \cos \theta  \, d\theta = r^2\int \cos^2\theta \, d\theta \, .
$$
Finally, we may use the identity
$$
\cos^2\theta \equiv \frac{\cos(2\theta)+1}{2}
$$
to obtain
$$
r^2 \int \frac{\cos(2\theta)+1}{2} \, d\theta = r^2 \int \frac{\cos(2\theta)+1}{2} \, d\theta = r^2\left(\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \, .
$$
Note that when $x=r$, $\theta = \arcsin(1) = \pi/2$; when $x=-r$, $\theta = - \pi/2$. So the area of a circle is
$$
2 \int_{-r}^{r} \sqrt{r^2-x^2} \, dx \, = 2 \left[r^2\left(\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right]_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} = \pi r^2 \, .
$$
Admittedly, this was not the most elegant of proofs, but I'm wondering if it is mathematically rigorous.

Comment: It seems correct.